# JAR is executed with terminal but not with direct clicking

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have tried the following:

1. in terminal it works
2. In Intellij it works
3. I have tried to launch it with javaw.exe but nothing changes

Are there any other options?

Comment: Please show us how you built the jar file (what is in the manifest?), how you are exactly invoking it on the command line and what output you get?

Comment: The terminal output is exactly my GUi, the manifest is in src/ directory, where the main class is src/sample/Main.class

Comment: java -jar myjarlocation.jar

Comment: In Windows, you can right click on the icon and set command line with arguments the same commands that worked on command line. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an OS problem that an application building one -- because you said that it works in your IDE and terminal.

Make sure that you installed Java properly in your machine.

In Windows/MacOs, after installing Java, the `*.jar` files are automatically associated with the `java -jar` command and makes it runnable via double-click.

In linux, this varies on the flavour or DE you are using. But there's probably a utility in your OS to open `*.jar` files using `java -jar` command.